# Bathroom sink leak (not washer)

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, plumbing-fixture

Could you help me, please, I attached images and I have questions about them.

1. How black part of the sink calling? (orange box)
2. Is this part of the sink or is it a replacement part?
3. My sink is leaking because of metal corrosion (red box). How I can fix it? Can I do it myself?

Thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems to be the overflow drain has corroded. Depending on the manufacturer, you may be able to purchase this as a repair part, but I doubt it.

Comment: Location of repair makes it quite difficult, plus it looks like almost a dozen more ready to pop.  Part does look like it is added to sink during manufacture, so depending on age, replacement might be available if you are very lucky.